# Guid inconsistency in 2.0?

Tags: bug, status-completed, timeline, revisions

[question timeline](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question-timeline) returns

```
"revision_guid": "335659EE-8983-4BEC-BACC-CC95784A4465"
```

[revisions by guid](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-guids) return

```
"revision_guid": "335659ee89834becbacccc95784a4465"
```

Is there any particular reason for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this was a serialization bug.

A fix has been deployed.